# Can't mod weapons in New Vegas

Tags: mods, fallout-new-vegas

I just bought a scope for my hunting rifle and when I moused over it and pressed x nothing happened. The option to mod it isn't grayed out, and I've tried buying other weapons and mods and they didn't work either. I know it isn't a gra/non-gra issue, and I can't think of anything else. I only have a couple mods for the game, and I tried disabling them with the same results. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: I forgot to include the mods I use, I have NVSE as well as a mod that lets you smoke cigarettes (https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/49677) and one that gives you the wild wasteland trait for free (https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/35653). None of these edit/add weapon mods so I don't think there should be a conflict, but I removed them (NVSE included) and made a new character and still couldn't mod weapons. I validated my game files (I forgot that was an option or I would have tried that before making a post) and it said that one failed to validate and will be reaquired. I validated them again after it finished downloading and got the same results multiple times. I imagine this is the issue, so I'll be doing a fresh install. If the issue persists I'll update the post.

Comment: Disabling alone might not work, especially if you continue to test with your current character. Can you reproduce the problem with a new character (maybe use console commands to get yourself sone weapons and mods)? I'm pretty sure this is due to mods.

Comment: Can you also provide the names of the couple of mods you use?

Comment: I edited the post to include that info

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled new vegas and verified the game files and got the same issue with one file failing to validate. I tried to run it anyway, first without any mods and a new save it worked fine. Then i reinstalled the mods I was using and loaded my current save and had no issues. I don't know why it works, but it works now.

Comment: Yes, that happens occasionally with mods: things get overwritten in the wrong order, and it causes bugs. I think in this case it's the Wild Wasteland perk mod, because it contains (a) script(s) to prevent you from finding certain weapons. Or maybe you or the mod author did or did not clean files beforehand, and you get wrong or missing references, and all that jazz. Glad it's working now, though :)

Comment: I hadn't thought about the fact that wild wasteland makes certain weapons available/unavailable I think you're right and it was definitely that. Thanks! :)